# Storing credentials inside slack framework, needed by custom app for slack api integration

Tags: slack, slack-api

For a custom integration, we are looking an a scenario where we want to save some access keys in private variables during transaction. Currently we are planning on using heroku as platform and node.js as the framework. Now we don't want to store these variables inside either node.js or heroku, as it would still be accessible from outside slack. Do we have any mechanism where we can store such values inside the slack framework and then access them? Using slack user datatable or something similar?

Comment: To store credentials and secrets, you are probably looking for Heroku environment variables https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 0):

Slack **does not** have a mechanism to store credentials.

As a workaround you can post the credentials to some private channel and can retrieve it from there.
 **But it is not recommended.**

Ideally you should store these credentials to a secure encrypted place.

 May be you should use some kind of secure database/cache/cloud vault.